# create redis cluster v5 with docker-compose error

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

#### Prepare Environment

this docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  redis-master1:
    image: redis:5.0
    container_name: redis-master1
    working_dir: /config
    ports:
      - 6391:6391
      - 16391:16391
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    network_mode: host
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /dvolumn/redis/config:/config
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/bash
      - redis.sh
```

redis.sh

```
redis-server /config/nodes-6391.conf
```

nodes-6391.conf: is a copy of "https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/5.0/redis.conf" 
critical change

```
cluster-enabled yes
port 6391
cluster-node-timeout 15000
cluster-config-file nodes-6391.conf
```

#### Run and Error

```
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose logs redis-master1
# the error infomation below: 

Attaching to redis-master1
redis-master1    |  # oO0OoO0OoO0Oo Redis is starting oO0OoO0OoO0Oo
redis-master1    |  # Redis version=5.0.9, bits=64, commit=00000000, modified=0, pid=6, just started
redis-master1    |  # Configuration loaded
redis-master1    |  # Unrecoverable error: corrupted cluster config file.
```

it shows that Unrecoverable error: corrupted cluster config file
but, the file "nodes-6391.conf" is a copy of "https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/5.0/redis.conf"
how is it corrupted ?

How should i fix it ?

Comment: what is your OS? What happens if you start redis with the original config file, without changing it?

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I get another way to create redis cluster.    If you're interested, you can see this https://github.com/8823Senior/magnificentJava/blob/master/doc/Docker%E6%90%AD%E5%BB%BARedis-Cluster%E9%9B%86%E7%BE%A4.md.   it's written in chinese.